# How to solve project Euler #12 in Lua?

Tags: lua, factors

Ok, here it goes another Euler problem question.
I've started to learn Lua by solving Euler project problems and got stuck on Euler [problem 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12).

It looks to me very straightforward and I don't understand why is my result incorrect?
Here is my solution so far:

```
-- return triangular number of the specified number
function get_tri_num(num)
  local n = 0
  for i=1, num do
    n = n + i
  end
  return n
end

-- return all factors of the specifeid number
function factors(num)
  local factors = {}
  for i=1, num/2 do
    if num%i == 0 then
      factors[#factors+1] = i
    end
  end
  factors[#factors+1] = num
  return factors
end

-- get the first triangle number with >500 divisors
function euler12()
  local n = 0
  local trinum = 1
  while true do
    n = n + 7
    trinum = get_tri_num(n)
    if #factors(trinum) > 500 then break end
  end
  print(trinum, n)
end

euler12()
```

This problem is computation intensive, well, at least the way I am solving it, so I use `luajit`.

```
time luajit euler12.lua 
103672800   14399

real    3m14.971s
user    3m15.033s
sys 0m0.000s
```

First, I try this solution on the toy example provided in the problem description. Changing the line of `euler12()` to `if #factors(trinum) > 5 then break end`, I get:

```
28  7
```

Which corresponds to the results shown in the problem example.

Second, after I see that the toy example is working I run `euler12()` with `>500` condition. According to my solution the answer is **103672800** and yes, if I separately check the number of divisors for this result is >500:

```
print(#factors(103672800))
648
```

But...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
while true do
  n = n + 7
```

Why does `n` increaments `7` each time? That doesn't make sense, change it to `1`, and you could get the correct answer.

---

However, the performance is still poor. Several places that could be improved:

- Every time the function `get_tri_num` is called, it's calculating
  from scratch, that's not necessary.
- You don't need the factors of a number, you only need the number of
  factors of a number, so why return a table in `factors`?
- `for i=1, num/2 do` is not necessary. Iterating to the square root of
  `num` is enough to get the number of factors.

Refer to [my code](https://github.com/yuhao600/project-euler/blob/master/src/012.Highly%20divisible%20triangular%20number/012.lua) for the same problem.

Comment: Cause in the problem they show that 7th number gets most factors, so I thought that it was done intentionally to show that you may find it by checking only each 7th number.

I see, thank you for your comments.

Comment: Some other ways to save on performance is if you need the factors of numbers A LOT in your program, to cache them.

Comment: And his while true do loop could be a ```for n = 1,math.huge do``` so he doesn't have to manually increment it (not sure if this is more efficient or not though)

Comment: Instead of breaking the while loop he can return n directly. Ending the whole function.

Comment: Just some ideas there if you're looking to optimize it.